# ASP.NET InitComplete event

Tags: asp.net

Can i Consider the responsibility of InitComplete event as follows

1) It is the last stage of page initialization

2) If ViewState is enabled at page level it will calls Page.TrackViewState() method inorder            to   make the view state to be ready for persisted across postback.

Thanks
Babu

Comment: Come on...giving you the benefit of a doubt, the other question you asked, the answer linked you to the same MSDN documentation page I used to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

> Raised at the end of the page's initialization stage. **Only one operation takes place between the Init and InitComplete events: tracking of view state changes is turned on.** View state tracking enables controls to persist any values that are programmatically added to the ViewState collection. Until view state tracking is turned on, any values added to view state are lost across postbacks. Controls typically turn on view state tracking immediately after they raise their Init event.
>
> **Use this event to make changes to view state that you want to make sure are persisted after the next postback.**
>
> 1) It is the last stage of page initialization

Yep

> 2) If ViewState is enabled at page level it will calls Page.TrackViewState() method inorder to make the view state to be ready for persisted across postback.

Nope, by the time you get to InitComplete, ViewState tracking has already been turned on.  As the last section of the documentation states, purpose of the even is to changes to the ViewState.